# 'OVRCameraController' could not be found. Are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, oculus

I have a difficulty finding answers of errors.
Errors are as follows :

> Assets/OVR/Scripts/OVRCamera.cs(73,17): error CS0246: The type or
>   namespace name `OVRCameraController' could not be found. Are you
>   missing a using directive or an assembly reference?
>
> Assets/OVR/Scripts/OVRCamera.cs(507,16): error CS0246: The type or
>   namespace name `OVRCameraController' could not be found. Are you
>   missing a using directive or an assembly reference?
>
> Assets/OVR/Scripts/OVRCrosshair.cs(41,16): error CS0246: The type or
>   namespace name `OVRCameraController' could not be found. Are you
>   missing a using directive or an assembly reference?
>
> Assets/OVR/Scripts/OVRCrosshair.cs(84,48): error CS0246: The type or
>   namespace name `OVRCameraController' could not be found. Are you
>   missing a using directive or an assembly reference?
>
> Assets/OVR/Scripts/OVRMainMenu.cs(78,17): error CS0246: The type or
>   namespace name `OVRCameraController' could not be found. Are you
>   missing a using directive or an assembly reference?
>
> Assets/OVR/Scripts/OVRVisionGuide.cs(45,17): error CS0246: The type or
>   namespace name `OVRCameraController' could not be found. Are you
>   missing a using directive or an assembly reference?
>
> Assets/OVR/Scripts/OVRVisionGuide.cs(201,48): error CS0246: The type
>   or namespace name `OVRCameraController' could not be found. Are you
>   missing a using directive or an assembly reference?

How to solve these errors?

Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`OVRPlayerController` is from Oculus SDK Unity 4 Integration ~v0.24. This was made for Unity 4 and is now considered a Legacy plugin. The latest version does not contain all those classes in your error message.You can get the legacy version by clicking on **Details** next to [**Unity 4.x Legacy Integration V1.3.0**](https://developer.oculus.com/downloads/).  For the latest version which means you have to start your project over, simply download [Oculus Utilities for Unity 5 V1.5.0](https://developer.oculus.com/downloads/).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have one more question. My Unity Version is Unity 5.3.5f PRO Version. So, do I delete some classes related to Unity 4? And then, do I load Oculus Utilities for Unity 5 ver. package ?

Comment: Yes. Please make backup of your project. The current plugin you have is very old. You have to remove the OVR folder and any Oculus plugins from your project. Follow direction here https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/VRDevices-Oculus.html

Comment: Thanks very much. I solve this error. You're very kind! :)